# How to fix VueTinySlider with VueMaterial cards when implementing Darkmode

Tags: vue-material

I've set up the darkmode best practices on my PWA.

When I add in the Dark Mode Opt Out switch - only some of my VueTinySlider VueMaterial cards are updated to my theme. The last card is not updated, and remains white.

Here is how I'm getting and setting darkmode with vue:

```
darkmode: {
  get() {
    return this.$store.state.darkmode;
  },
  set() {
    this.$store.commit('toggleDarkmode');
  }
}
```

I'm using:

```
VueTinySlider - v0.1.35
VueMaterial - v1.0.0-beta-11
```

What am I doing wrong?

I expect all cards to be updated to match the theme applied.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I came across this issue. It seems like there might be a bug in VueTinySlider when `loop=true`

When designing darkmode for my PWA. I ended up hooking into the `updated` hook in Vue.

You can check it out the API here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated

I updated my `Card.vue` component to update the cards style and apply the correct theme. This should work:

```
updated() {
    const currentTheme = this.darkmode ? 'dark' : 'light'
    const oldTheme = this.darkmode ? 'light' : 'dark'

    if (this.$refs.tinySlider) {
      const cards = this.$refs.tinySlider.$el.getElementsByClassName(`md-card md-theme-${oldTheme}`)

      while (cards.length > 0) {
        for (let card of cards) {
          card.classList.remove(`md-theme-${oldTheme}`)
          card.classList.add(`md-theme-${currentTheme}`)
        }
      }
    }
  },
```